# Selecting Checkboxes present in VBA Frame are not triggering any event

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have created user form with one Frame having some checkboxes. Next to the frame I have button. The flow is like I have to select checkboxes and then click on the Button to do get some data.

But I want to do is that I don't want button to be enabled until I select any of the checkboxes in frame. I used "Enter/Click" event procedures none of them worked.

Below is what I tried and still `Commandbutton2` is not getting enabled.

Can anyone please help me to get over this problem?

```
Private Sub Frame1_enter()

For Each C In Frame1.Controls

If TypeOf C Is MSForms.CheckBox Then

   If C.Value = True Then
  Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = True
  Exit Sub

End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old but here is a solution.  Unfortunately, you will need to handle the `Change` event for each `Checkbox` individually.  At least the logic can be factored out into a separate method.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
  SetButtonEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
  SetButtonEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Change()
  SetButtonEnabled
End Sub

Sub SetButtonEnabled()
  Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = ValidateChecks
End Sub

Function ValidateChecks() As Boolean

  Dim cbx As MSForms.CheckBox
  Dim ctl As Control
  Dim bSomethingChecked As Boolean

  For Each ctl In Me.Frame1.Controls

    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
      Debug.Print "Found checkbox : " & ctl.Name
      Set cbx = ctl
      If cbx.Value Then
        bSomethingChecked = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Else
      Debug.Print ctl.Name & " is not a checkbox: " & ctl.Name
    End If
  Next
  Set cbx = Nothing
  Set ctl = Nothing
  ValidateChecks = bSomethingChecked
End Function
```